# Как загрузить меню для сайта из базы только один раз?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Проблема в том, что при каждом обновлении страницы (`Layout.cshtml`) из базы загружается меню.

Есть идея создать класс по типу Singleton, или хранить в объекте `Session`. Какое решение посоветуете?

Модель:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public int? Parameter { get; set; }
}

public class NavBlockViewModel
{
    public NavBlockViewModel()
    {
        MenuItems = new List<Menu>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Menu> MenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
public class CommonController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult GetNavigationBlock()
    {
        IList<Menu> menuItems = _repo.GetMenu();            
        if (menuItems != null || menuItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var model = new NavBlockViewModel();
            model.MenuItems = menuItems;
            model.Name = "Главное";
            return View(model);
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Layout.cshtml

```
//остальной код
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetNavigationBlock", "Common"); }
//остальной код
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Один из простых вариантов решения - использовать **OutputCacheAttribute** для GetNavigationBlock():

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue)]
public ActionResult GetNavigationBlock()
```

Длительность хранения задаётся через свойство **Duration** в секундах. Также она может быть вынесена в профиль (свойство **CacheProfile**) для настройки через **web.config**.